# how to get the id of a response from an axios API call -- Axios with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, axios

I'm using axios to make a POST request to post information and send it to the Database. After that, I declare .then to get the response of the POST request. I want to get the id of the record I just created. So I did response.config.data.id but it didn't work. So I was wondering what should I call exactly to get the ID of the new record I just POSTED?

This is my code:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   streetname: '',
   zipcode: '',
   city: '',
   country: ''
  };
 }

 onSubmit = () => {
  const { streetname, zipcode, city, country } = this.state;
  axios
   .post('http://localhost:3000/addresses', {
    address: {
     streetname,
     zipcode,
     city,
     country
    }
   })
   .then(response => {
    console.log(response.config.data.id);
   });
 };

 render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
     style={{ height: 40, width: 80, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }}
     onChangeText={streetname => this.setState({ streetname })}
     value={this.state.streetname}
    />
    <TextInput
     style={{ height: 40, width: 80, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }}
     onChangeText={zipcode => this.setState({ zipcode })}
     value={this.state.zipcode}
    />
    <TextInput
     style={{ height: 40, width: 80, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }}
     onChangeText={city => this.setState({ city })}
     value={this.state.city}
    />
    <TextInput
     style={{ height: 40, width: 80, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2 }}
     onChangeText={country => this.setState({ country })}
     value={this.state.country}
    />
    <Button onPress={() => this.onSubmit()} title="Submit" color="#00ff00" />
   </View>
  );
 }
}


export default RegistrationForm;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center'
 }
});
```

This is my console.log(response):

```html
{data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: undefined, headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config
:
adapter
:
ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
data
:
"{"address":{"streetname":"Downtowb","zipcode":"1882RD","city":"Cairo","country":"Egypt"}}"
headers
:
Accept
:
"application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type
:
"application/json;charset=utf-8"
__proto__
:
Object
maxContentLength
:
-1
method
:
"post"
timeout
:
0
transformRequest
:
0
:
ƒ transformRequest(data, headers)
__proto__
:
Object
transformResponse
:
0
:
ƒ transformResponse(data)
__proto__
:
Object
url
:
"http://localhost:3000/addresses"
validateStatus
:
ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName
:
"XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName
:
"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__
:
Object
data
:
status
:
"address created successfully"
__proto__
:
constructor
:
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
:
ƒ toString()
valueOf
:
ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__
:
ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__
:
ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__
:
ƒ __proto__()
headers
:
cache-control
:
"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
content-type
:
"application/json; charset=utf-8"
etag
:
"W/"0783f7a5f6931c50f5c5803429269854""
referrer-policy
:
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
transfer-encoding
:
"Identity"
x-content-type-options
:
"nosniff"
x-download-options
:
"noopen"
x-frame-options
:
"SAMEORIGIN"
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies
:
"none"
x-request-id
:
"f7ab51f0-d6c8-4043-aefa-f5f420f059cb"
x-runtime
:
"0.071757"
x-xss-protection
:
"1; mode=block"
__proto__
:
Object
request
:
XMLHttpRequest
DONE
:
4
HEADERS_RECEIVED
:
2
LOADING
:
3
OPENED
:
1
UNSENT
:
0
onabort
:
(...)
onerror
:
(...)
onload
:
(...)
onloadend
:
(...)
onloadstart
:
(...)
onprogress
:
(...)
onreadystatechange
:
(...)
ontimeout
:
(...)
readyState
:
4
responseHeaders
:
{X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: "none", X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block", Etag: "W/"0783f7a5f6931c50f5c5803429269854"", Transfer-Encoding: "Identity", X-Request-Id: "f7ab51f0-d6c8-4043-aefa-f5f420f059cb", …}
responseURL
:
"http://localhost:3000/addresses"
status
:
201
timeout
:
0
upload
:
XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {Symbol(listeners): {…}}
withCredentials
:
true
_aborted
:
false
_cachedResponse
:
undefined
_hasError
:
false
_headers
:
{}
_incrementalEvents
:
false
_lowerCaseResponseHeaders
:
{x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: "none", x-xss-protection: "1; mode=block", etag: "W/"0783f7a5f6931c50f5c5803429269854"", transfer-encoding: "Identity", x-request-id: "f7ab51f0-d6c8-4043-aefa-f5f420f059cb", …}
_method
:
"POST"
_requestId
:
null
_response
:
"{"status":"address created successfully"}"
_responseType
:
""
_sent
:
true
_subscriptions
:
[]
_timedOut
:
false
_trackingName
:
"unknown"
_url
:
"http://localhost:3000/addresses"
response
:
(...)
responseText
:
(...)
responseType
:
(...)
Symbol(listeners)
:
{readystatechange: {…}, error: {…}, timeout: {…}}
__proto__
:
EventTarget
onabort
:
(...)
onerror
:
(...)
onload
:
(...)
onloadend
:
(...)
onloadstart
:
(...)
onprogress
:
(...)
onreadystatechange
:
(...)
ontimeout
:
(...)
abort
:
ƒ abort()
addEventListener
:
ƒ addEventListener(type, listener)
constructor
:
ƒ XMLHttpRequest()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ getAllResponseHeaders()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ getResponseHeader(header)
open
:
ƒ open(method, url, async)
response
:
(...)
responseText
:
(...)
responseType
:
(...)
send
:
ƒ send(data)
setReadyState
:
ƒ setReadyState(newState)
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ setRequestHeader(header, value)
setResponseHeaders
:
ƒ setResponseHeaders(responseHeaders)
setTrackingName
:
ƒ setTrackingName(trackingName)
__didCompleteResponse
:
ƒ __didCompleteResponse(requestId, error, timeOutError)
__didCreateRequest
:
ƒ __didCreateRequest(requestId)
__didReceiveData
:
ƒ __didReceiveData(requestId, response)
__didReceiveDataProgress
:
ƒ __didReceiveDataProgress(requestId, loaded, total)
__didReceiveIncrementalData
:
ƒ __didReceiveIncrementalData(requestId, responseText, progress, total)
__didReceiveResponse
:
ƒ __didReceiveResponse(requestId, status, responseHeaders, responseURL)
__didUploadProgress
:
ƒ __didUploadProgress(requestId, progress, total)
_clearSubscriptions
:
ƒ _clearSubscriptions()
_reset
:
ƒ _reset()
get response
:
ƒ ()
get responseText
:
ƒ ()
get responseType
:
ƒ ()
set responseType
:
ƒ (responseType)
__proto__
:
EventTarget
status
:
201
statusText
:
undefined
__proto__
:
Object
```

***UPDATE TO THE QUESTION I ASKED***

The backend I make the POST request to is a rails backend. Below is the create method inside my address_controller. I return Address.last.id but nothing gets returned in my console.log(response).

```html
class AddressesController < ActionController::API
    
    def show
        address = Address.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def create
        address = Address.new(address_params)
      
        if address.save
          render json: {status: 'address created successfully'}, status: :created
          return Address.last.id
        else
          render json: { errors: address.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
        end 
    end 
    
    def address_params
        params.require(:address).permit(:streetname, :zipcode, :city, :country)
    end
  
end
```

Comment: response.data why do you do response.config?

Comment: ok so its 'response.data.id' ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear if you don't provide an example of the returned data. Make a console.log(response), copy and paste the whole returned data and update your question.

Comment: maybe post the output of console.log(response) and look how the data is structured in there

Comment: @davidbucka I edited my question to have the console.log(response). I can't find the id of the record I just create. I keep looking on the whole log but there is no indication id. That's why I posted the questions in the first. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently had the same issue. I had to update the database query. I'm using stored procedures within **MS SQL**. If you are using SQL, At the end of the query add:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This will give you the Id of the new record back.

**Updated query example**

```
INSERT INTO tbl (value1, value2) VALUES (A, B)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The above example will insert a record, then once complete will return the ID of the rows affected.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi @LukeWalker96, thanks for sharing. I'm using SQL yes. I actually get the data from a small rest api I've built using rails. Do you where I should  add the sql query you shared exactly, if i'm using rails & active record? Thanks again for sharing!

Comment: No problem. Directly at the end of your query. i will update my answer to include a proper example. Say your constructing your sql query problematically, add the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() directly after your Insert query.

Comment: Hi @LukeWalker96 constructing my sql queries problematically.. I'm using ActiveRecord with rails to do that. Do you know by any chance return the id from my rails controller? I did Address.last.id but its not returning anything ...

Comment: Can you please update your post to include the query your using? May be easier for me to explain from here if i can.

Comment: Try calling Address.id after the second to last `end`

Comment: Where exactly can I find the id in the console.log(response) if I'm doing everything correctly? Maybe its returning something but I just cannot find it! I tried calling it like how you said I should call it, and its successfully creating the post request, but I just can't find the id

Comment: usually you will see an array of rows affected? Mine outputs to say result.data.recordset[0] - suppose this could vary though. Sorry if that's not much help.